# Why won't my grep-filtered string print from within a while-loop?

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

Tried to keep my code as simple as possible:

1: What are the rules for using echo within a while loop?
All my $a and some of my $word variables are echoed not my echo kk?

2: What is the scope of my count variable? Why is it not working within my while loop? can I extend the variable to make it global?

3: When I use the grep in the final row the $word cariable only prints the first word in the passing rows ehile if I remove the grep line in the end $work functions as intended and prints all the words.

```
count=1
while read a; do
    ((count=count+1))
    if [ $count -le 2 ]
    then
        echo $a
        echo kk
        for word in $a; do
            echo $word
        done
    fi
done < data.txt | grep Iteration
```

Comment: some `echo` commands are discarded because you're filtering the output with `grep`. Ex: kk does not contain "Iteration" so it will never be issued!

Comment: Great thanks that explains a lot of the strange results. I thtought I was using grep on data.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use Process Substitution

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792565/scope-of-variables-in-bash-and-rules-for-printing-variables-inside-loops#comment68807556_40792565), you say:

> I thtought I was using grep on data.txt *(sic)*

No. Your current pipeline passes the loop's *results* through grep, not the source file. To do that, you need to rewrite your redirection to use [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst). For example:

```
count=1
while read a; do
    ((count=count+1))
    if [ $count -le 2 ]
    then
        echo $a
        echo kk
        for word in $a; do
            echo $word
        done
    fi
done < <(fgrep Iteration data.txt)
```

Comment: Since [`fgrep` is deprecated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/fgrep.html), I guess it makes sense to use `grep -F` in new code.

Comment: @TomFenech The document you're pointing to is from 1997. If they haven't disappeared by now, I doubt fgrep or egrep are going away anytime soon. I have yet to run into modern a Linux or BSD distro (including macOS) that doesn't include them, but admittedly YMMV.

Comment: Probably because everyone keeps using them! :^)

Answer (score 2):

@CodeGnome answered your question but there's other problems with your script that will come back to bite you at some point. (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for discussions on some of them and also google quoting shell variables). Just don't do it. Shell scripts are just for sequencing calls to tools and the UNIX tool for manipulating text is awk. In this case all you'd need to do the job robustly, portably and efficiently would be:

```
awk '
/Iteration/ {
    if (++count <= 2) {
        print
        print "kk"
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            print $i
        }
    }
}' data.txt
```

and of course it'd be more efficient still if you just stop reading the input when count hits 2:

```
awk '
/Iteration/ {
    print
    print "kk"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $i
    }
    if (++count == 2) {
        exit
    }
}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [CodeGnome's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40792932/45375) with an **explanation of how your command actually works and why it doesn't do what you want**:

In Bash's grammar, an input redirection such as `< data.txt` is part of a *single* command, whereas `|`, the pipe symbol, chains *multiple* commands, from *left to right*, to form a *pipeline*.

Technically, `while ... done ... < data.txt | grep Iteration` is a single pipeline composed of 2 commands:

- a single *compound command* (`while ...; do ...; done`) with an input redirection (`< data.txt`),
- and a *simple command* (`grep Iteration`) that receives the stdout output from the compound command via its stdin, courtesy of the pipe.

In other words:

- *only* the contents of `data.txt` is fed to the `while` loop as input (via stdin),
- and whatever stdout output the `while` loop produces is *then* sent to the next pipeline segment, the `grep` command.

---

By contrast, it sounds like you want to apply `grep` to `data.txt` *first*, and only sent *the matching lines* to the `while loop`.

You have the following options for **sending a command's output to another command**:

<sup>Note: The following solutions use a simplified `while` loop for brevity - whether a `while` command is single-line or spans multiple lines is irrelevant.

Also, instead of using input redirection (`< data.txt`) to pass the file content to `grep`, `data.txt` is passed as a *filename argument*.</sup>

**Option 1: Place the command** whose output to send to your `while` loop ***first* in the pipeline**:

```
grep 'Iteration' data.txt | while read -r a; do echo "$a"; done
```

The down-side of this approach is that your **`while` loop then runs in a *subshell*** (as all segments of a pipeline do by default), which means that **variables defined or modified in your `while` command won't be visible to the *current* shell**.

In Bash v4.2+, you can **fix this by running `shopt -s lastpipe`**, which tells Bash to run the *last* pipeline segment - the `while` command in this case - in the *current* shell instead.
Note that `lastpipe` is a nonstandard `bash` extension to the POSIX standard.
(To try this in an *interactive* shell, you must first turn off job control with `set +m`.)

---

**Option 2: Use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)**:

Loosely speaking, a process substitution `<(...)` allows you to present command output as the content of a temporary file that cleans up after itself.
Since `<(...)` expands to the temporary file's (FIFO's) *path*, and `read` in the `while` loop only accepts *stdin* input, input redirection must be applied as well: `< <(...)`:

```
while read -r a; do echo "$a"; done < <(grep 'Iteration' data.txt)
```

The advantage of this approach is that the `while` loop runs in the *current* subshell, and any variables definitions or modifications therefore remain in scope after the command completes.

The potential down-side of this approach is that process substitutions are a nonstandard `bash` extension to the POSIX standard (although `ksh` and `zsh` support them too).

---

**Option 3: Use a command substitution inside a here-document**:

Using the command first in the pipeline (option 1) is a POSIX-compliant approach, but doesn't allow you to modify variables in the *current* shell (and Bash's `lastpipe` option is not POSIX-compliant).

The only **POSIX-compliant way to send command output to a command that runs in the *current* shell** is to use a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`$(...)`) inside a double-quoted [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument):

```
while read -r a; do echo "$a"; done <<EOF
$(grep 'Iteration' data.txt)
EOF
```

---

**Streamlining your code and making it more robust**:

The rest of your code has some non-obvious pitfalls that are worth addressing:

- **Double-quote your variable references** (e.g., `echo "$a"` instead of `echo $a`), unless you specifically want word-splitting and globbing (filename expansion) applied to the values; word splitting and globbing are two kinds of [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).
- Similarly, **don't use `for` to iterate over an (of necessity unquoted) variable reference** (don't use `for word in $a`, in your case), unless you want globbing applied to the individual words - see what happens when you run `$a='one *'; for word in $a; do echo "$word"; done`
  You could turn globbing off beforehand (`set -f`) and back on after (`set +f`), but it's better to use `read -ra words ...` to read the words into an *array* first, and then safely iterate over the array elements with `for word in "${words[@]}"; ...`- note the `"..."` around the array variable reference.
- **Always use `-r` with `read`**; without it, rarely used `\`-preprocessing is applied, which will "eat" embedded `\` chars.

If we heed the advice above, apply a few additional tweaks, and use a process substitution to feed `grep`'s output to the `while` loop, we get:

```
count=1
while read -r a; do # Note the -r
    if (( ++count <= 2 )); then
        echo "$a"
        # Split $a safely into words and store the words in
        # array variable ${words[@]}.
        read -ra words <<<"$a" # Note the -a to read into an *array*.
        # Loop over the words (elements of the array).
        # Note: To simply print the words, you could use 
        #       `printf '%s\n' "${words[@]}"`` instead of the loop.
        for word in "${words[@]}"; do
            echo "$word"
        done
    fi
done < <(grep 'Iteration' data.txt)
```

Note: As written, you don't need a *loop* at all, because you always exit after the 1st iteration.

Finally, as a general alternative for larger input sets, consider [Ed Morton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815248/45375), which is *much faster due to using `awk`* to process your input file, whereas *looping in shell code is generally slow*.